# Is there any viscoelastic model directly specified from strain energy function?

Tags: continuum-mechanics

For most models I've seen, including the classic quasi-linear viscoelastic model, the parallel network viscoelastic model ABAQUS uses, and the model described in Holzapfel & Gasser 2000, they all seems to be directly defining the stress with respect of time rather than defining the strain energy function.

Is there such a model for viscoelasticity, that is directly specified from strain energy function?

Thank you!

Comment: Only a hyperelastic constitutive model can be derived from a strain energy function. The dissipative behavior must be specified separately. If you'd like, I can provide a detailed answer, but it will be pretty lengthy.

Comment: @TylerOlsen Thank you so much for your response! Please do, and I'd really be happy to hear about it if you may. Is that a strain-energy form is hard to be defined in prior, because the strain-energy is indeed dependent on the history of stimuli? (So far the most related work I have read is the Holzapfel & Gasser 2000, and also in Holzapfel's book, and I'd be happy to hear about more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a viscoelastic material, there is no well defined *strain energy density function* (SEDF), because there is a dissipative material and, therefore, energy is not conserved.

What does happen is that when the strain rate tends to zero, any viscoelastic material approaches its behavior to that of an elastic material (and under very general assumptions, generally hyperelastic). And then, for that limit (hyper)elastic behaviour, you can use a SEDF $\psi(\varepsilon_{ij})$.

From that SEDF for the limit behavior and assuming a (separable) *quasi-linear viscoelastic* (QLVE) behavior, then the stress-strain relationships are given by:

$$\sigma_{ij}(t) = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \epsilon_{ij}} + \int_0^t G_{ijkl}(t-\tau)\frac{\text{d}\varepsilon_{kl}(\tau)}{\text{d}\tau}\text{d}\tau $$

In fact, the latter expression, allows the definition of a QLVE model for any reasonable SEDF $\psi$. For the relaxation function $G_{ijkl}(t)$, you can use usually a Prony series:

$$G_{ijkl}(t) = \sum_{p=1}^N C_{ijklm} e^{-t/\tau_p}$$